# Редактирование степени числа

Tags: java, android, xml, edittext

*Как замечательно что есть такой форум на котором можно задавать вопросы. Потому что голову уже сломал.*

Нужно сделать следующие

[image: Пункт 1]

[image: Пункт 2]

[image: Пункт 3]

[image: Пункт 4]

[image: Пункт 5]

Это Item в ListView в нем EditText и ниже с выравниваем по правому краю TextView

Речь идет о EditText как в нем реализовать данный функционал.
Что бы можно было динамически двигаться по выражению и если это степень то возносить курсор к степени и была возможность ее редактировать.

Нужно что бы при нажатии кнопки степени.
Курсор поднимался в верхнюю половину пользователь вводил степень а дальше мог спустится к выражению и дописать его.

Это возможно реализовать в одном EditText или для степени динамически создается EditText.
Как вообще дать возможность юзеру записать число в степень?

Как вообще это можно сделать?

Спасибо огромное.

**UPDATE**

Получилось спасибо, большое.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDATE 2**

Как поднять курсор в степень как на 3-4 рисунке? Есть идеи?

**UPDATE 3**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Реализовал кнопку возведения в квадрат. Ну такое на самом деле не знаю насколько это лучший способ

Сейчас осталось сделать

1.перемещение курсора внутрь степени

2.динамическое добавление туда

кому интересно репа [тут](https://github.com/lirugo/Calculate) - *commit Implemented Sqr button*

Comment: тоже интересно узнать как это делается:)

Comment: ну и где решение-то? В принятом ответе что-то нет кода, как поднимать курсор и вводить степень. Там только как вывести уже готовый текст.

Comment: По поводу вводить в степень из кода все ясно.
По поводу поднятия курсора - да он не поднимается
Найду как это сделать отпишу.

Доделаю свою реализацию добавлю решение к вопросу

Возможно у кого то есть идеи как правильно поднять курсор?

Comment: можно попробовать `editText.setSelection(0)` в вашем случае на рисунке 3 это будет  `editText.setSelection(2)`

Comment: editText.setSelection(0) - вообще не совсем то что нужно, оно просто указывает где поставить курсор.

Comment: да но ведь вам нужно как-то перемещаться по тексту внутри, или вы хотите не программно задавать перемещение в самостоятельно выбирать ту цифру которая вам нужна?

Comment: Кто то может помочь?
Застрял на этом моменте
Динамическое изменение курсора в EditText
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/897338/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B2-edittext

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант можно воспользоваться классом HTML для форматирования введенного текста:

```
private static CharSequence formatPower(String source) {
 int powerPosition = source.indexOf("E");
 if (powerPosition == -1) {
 return source;
 }
 String numberValue = source.substring(0, powerPosition);
 String powerValue = source.substring(powerPosition + 1);
 return fromHtml(numberValue + "<sup>" + powerValue + "</sup>");
}
private static Spanned fromHtml(String html) {
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
 return Html.fromHtml(html,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
 } else {
 return Html.fromHtml(html);
 }
}
```

и дальше уже делать так:

```
mEditText.setText(formatPower("1.0E20"));
```

нашел этот способ в сети, надеюсь он вам поможет в решении вашей проблемы.